# How to set Bordertop black to div having black opacity background color

Tags: html, css, border

I have a Div with `Backgroundcolor` black and `opacity` 0.6. 
Now i want to set bordertop to black color without opacity

**CSS:**

```
 #MainHeader
    {
        position:relative;
        top:0px;
        height:50px;
        width:1000px;
        opacity:0.7;
        background-color:black;
        border-top:10px solid black;
     }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="MainHeader"></div>
```

**[JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hJzgh/2/)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `RGB` to give background color & opacity

```
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    /* For IE 5.5 - 7*/
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000);
    /* For IE 8*/
   -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000)";
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hJzgh/6/)**

Check the detailed explanation [**here**](http://userinterfacehome.blogspot.in/2012/08/transparency-for-background-color.html)

Comment: Thank you very much Sowmya, and also am gonna follow ur blog

Comment: @satindersingh Pleasure :)

Answer (score 1):

Use **rgba** background color instead of opacity.

```
MainHeader {
position:relative;
top:0px;
height:50px;
width:1000px;
background-color:rgba(67, 67, 69, 0.6);  // use this instead of opacity
border-top:10px solid #000000;
}
```